# Recursive implementation of palindrome test

Tags: python, palindrome

I was asked to define a recursive function that

- takes in a string
  and
- returns True if the string is a palindrome, False if not

I thought since I must check string for whitespaces that could be the perfect opportunity to use a wrapper to include in my `isPalindrome()` function.

#### My code:

```
def rem_spaces(string, g=''):
    """
    parameters : string of type str;
    returns : a string with all the spaces removed
    """

    if len(string)==0:
        return g
    if string[0]!=' ':

        return rem_spaces(string[1:], g+string[0])
    return rem_spaces(string[1:], g)

def isPalindrome(string):
    """
    parameters : string of type str
    returns : True if the string is a palindrome, False if not
    """
    string=rem_spaces(string)
    if len(string) % 2 != 0:
        return False
    if len(string)==0:
        return True
    if string[0]==string[-1]:
        return isPalindrome(string[1:-1])
    return isPalindrome(string[1:-1])


print(isPalindrome('ferdihe            '))
```

will output the following:

```
True
```

**What is wrong with me code?**

Comment: A string with an odd number of characters can be a palindrome.

Comment: You can replaced the whole `rem_spaces` function with the str method `.strip` to remove the desired caracters. For example `string.strip(" ")` returns the string without regular spaces while `string.strip()` with no argument deletes all forms of spacing: space, tab, line feed, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do something like this instead?

```
def ispalindrome(x):
    n=len(x)
    return x==x[::-1]

test = ' hannah '
ispalindrome(test)
#True

test = ' hannah'
ispalindrome(test)
#False
```

Comment: Is `test==test[::-1]` enough?

Comment: Because that's not recursive. Out of curiosity does `x==x[::-1]` shortcut?

Comment: Right I actually did not read the "recursive function" part. Yes, it does shortcut.

Comment: Ok thanks. Half related, I'm working on operations on big arrays at the moment and shortcuts are my obsession now.